# to get coordinates for tap or click on windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a canvas control, on click/ taps on anywhere on this control a small popup should open. I have a pop control, but i wanted the popup to show on the point the where user taps or clicks. How do i get the coordinates of the click/tap and the popup to open on the same location.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you already have a popup that appears on click, but not at the position you want?  Perhaps you should post the code from the click/tap event handler that generates the popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this..now it's up to you to implement any check condition on point captured according to canvas dimentions..i have used a textblock to show message you can use any other control..tempcanvas is your canvas name

```
private void tempCanvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(tempCanvas);

        TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock();
        textblock.Text = "hello i am here";
        textblock.Height = 200;
        textblock.Width = 300;
        Canvas.SetLeft(textblock, pt.Position.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(textblock, pt.Position.Y);
        textblock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        tempCanvas.Children.Add(textblock);
    }
```

hope it helps you..